# How do i make more than one button in pygame?

Tags: python, button, pygame

I have made this code but i´m not able to make more buttons if i copy it or anything
so is there anyway i can get more buttons in, in the way i have set this code up?
and is it possible to put into a def display_button() and call it in the loop?

```
def Main():

pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("segoe print", 16)

button_surf = pygame.Surface((60, 40))
button_rect = button_surf.get_rect()
button_surf.fill(WHITE)
button_rect.center = (500, 750)
txt_surf = my_font.render("LEFT", 1, BLACK)
txt_rect = txt_surf.get_rect(center=(30,20))
button_surf.blit(txt_surf, txt_rect)


Seconds = 0
Frame=0

gameExit = False
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    Screen.fill(BLACK)
    Screen.blit(button_surf, button_rect)
```

that is my code

Answer (score 1):

You should create a seperate function for buttons:

```
def button(x, y, w, h, inactive, active, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        gameDisplay.blit(active, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            action()
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(inactive, (x, y))
```

After you have done that, you can call it like this:

```
#For Example
button(100, 350, 195, 80, startBtn, startBtn_hover, game_loop)
```

Here is what each parameter means:

- x: x-coordinate of button
- y: y-coordinate of button
- w: width of button
- h: height of button
- active: picture of button when the mouse is hovering over it
- inactive: picture of button when it is idle
- action: the function executed when the button is clicked

Comment: Hope this answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the same code with different rect locations, and different variable names.

```
button_surf2 = pygame.Surface((60, 40))
button_rect2 = button_surf.get_rect()
button_surf2.fill(WHITE)
button_rect2.center = (600, 850)
txt_surf2 = my_font.render("LEFT", 1, BLACK)
txt_rect2 = txt_surf2.get_rect(center=(30,20))
button_surf2.blit(txt_surf2, txt_rect2)
```

Or, if you want it a bit neater, you could make a button class.

```
def Button:
    def __init__(self, width, height, center, text):
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.surface.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect.center = center
        self.textSurf = my_font.render(text, 1, BLACK)
        self.textRect = self.textSurf.get_rect(center = (30, 20))
        self.surf.blit(self.textSurf, self.textRect)
```

Then you should make a list of all your buttons, and iterate through them when you want to draw, or check for clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Groups](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)

I'm using these, here is example:

```
buttons = pygame.sprite.Group()
picnames = ["Play","Quit"]
place = y/2 - 10 * (len(picnames) - 1) - 8
for picname in picnames:
    button = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    button.name = picname
    button.image = pygame.image.load("pic/" + picname + ".PNG").convert_alpha()
    button.rect = button.image.get_rect()
    button.rect.center = (x/2, place)
    place += 20
    buttons.add(button)

buttons.draw(screen)
```

[Here](https://github.com/Brambor/Dogs-and-Sheeps/blob/master/simulation.py) is whole my code.